# AWS MSK Error : Could not look up partition metadata for offset backing store topic in allotted period

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

Am trying use AWS MSK connect with lenses plugin to sink data from Kafka cluster "managed by 3rd party" to amazon s3.
[image]
and am getting :

```
[Worker-001b25e1c610b1241] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not look up partition metadata for offset backing store topic in allotted period. This could indicate a connectivity issue, unavailable topic partitions, or if this is your first use of the topic it may have taken too long to create.
```

I have tried to setup ec2 server and use Kafka-consul-consumer and I was able to fetch data from the Kafka.

Any advice, why with using the lenses plugin not working ??

Configuration of the AWS MSK connector

```
{
    "connectorConfiguration": {
        "connector.class":"io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.aws.s3.sink.S3SinkConnector",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "connect.s3.kcql":"INSERT INTO bigdata-XXXX:output SELECT * FROM topic_name `JSON` WITH_FLUSH_INTERVAL = 5",
        "aws.region":"eu-central-1",
        "tasks.max":"1",
        "topics":"topic_name",
        "schema.enable":"false",
        "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "errors.log.enable":"true",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "allow.auto.create.topics " : "false",
        "connect.s3.aws.region": "eu-central-1",
        "connect.s3.vhost.bucket": "true",
        "aws.custom.endpoint":"https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"

    },
    "connectorName": "bigdata-transactions-connector",
    "kafkaCluster": {
        "apacheKafkaCluster": {
            "bootstrapServers": "kafka.XXXXXX:9092",
            "vpc": {
                "subnets": [
                    "subnet-XXXX",
                    "subnet-XXXX",
                    "subnet-XXXX"
                ],
                "securityGroups": ["sg-XXXXX"]
            }
        }
    },
    "capacity": {
        "provisionedCapacity": {
            "mcuCount": 1,
            "workerCount": 1
        }
    },
    "kafkaConnectVersion": "2.7.1",
    "serviceExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXX",
    "plugins": [
        {
            "customPlugin": {
                "customPluginArn": "arn:aws:XXXXX",
                "revision": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "logDelivery": { 
      "workerLogDelivery": { 
         "cloudWatchLogs": { 
            "enabled": true,
            "logGroup": "big_XXXXX"
         }
      }
   },
   "workerConfiguration": { 
      "revision": 1,
      "workerConfigurationArn": "arn:XXXXX"
   },
    "kafkaClusterEncryptionInTransit": {"encryptionType": "TLS"},
    "kafkaClusterClientAuthentication": {"authenticationType": "NONE"}
}
```

Comment: can I use AWS MSK connector with on prime Kafka  to read from ?

Comment: yes, you can. you need to ensure a connectivity between the VPC you deploy MSK Connector in and Kafka cluster on-prem. you successfully tried to connect from EC2 to a topic, but is EC2 deployed in the same VPC/same subnets as MSK Connector?

Comment: in the bootstrap-server configuration you are using port 9092, which is usually used for PLAINTEXT protocol, but in `kafkaClusterEncryptionInTransit` property you use TLS as an encryption type. Can you confirm you use TLS on 9092?

Answer (score 0):

The cluster is running on **9092**, which is a default for `PLAINTEXT` protocol:

```
"bootstrapServers": "kafka.XXXXXX:9092"
```

But in the properties of Client-Broker there is SSL:

```
"kafkaClusterEncryptionInTransit": {"encryptionType": "TLS"}
```

Error is not about accessing a data topic, but about accessing offset topic, which is used by worker, and also indicates possible connectivity issue:

> This could indicate a connectivity issue

Assuming the cluster is indeed on `PLAINTEXT`, the fix would be to change an encryption type:

```
"kafkaClusterEncryptionInTransit": {"encryptionType": "PLAINTEXT"}
```